# How can I remove a variable of a lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda

A code snippet sonarQube suggests removing the local variables that aren't used in the `lambda expression`. I still **don't deal with what's new in Java 8**, especially lambda expressions.
 How can I replace these variables that are not used? The IntelliJ doesn't suggest anything to me.

My code

```
    validation.stream().filter(aValidation -> aValidation.getSpec() != null).forEach(aValidation -> {
                if (aValidation.getArquivo() != null) {
                    String nomeOriginal = aValidation.getSpec().get("peca_nome").toString();
                    itemsValidacao.put(nomeOriginal, aValidation.getResultadoConsolidado());
                } else {
                    if (aValidation.getSpec().get("peca_nome") != null) {
                        String nomeOriginal = aValidation.getSpec().get("peca_nome").toString();
                        itemsValidacao.put(nomeOriginal, aValidation.getResultadoConsolidado());
                    }
                }
            });


 chaves.stream().filter(chave -> chave != null).forEach(chave -> {
            String value = cabecalho.get(chave);
            try {
                String novaChave = mapper.getChave(value.trim().toLowerCase());
                if (!novaChave.isEmpty()) {
                    cabecalhoNormalizado.put(novaChave, chave);
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.info(this, "Erro ao obter chave: " + value, e);
            }
        });
```

sonarQube
  Remove this unused "chave" local variable. 
  Remove this unused "aValidation" local variable.

Comment: To me it looks like a bug in sonarQube as those variables are definitely used in the source code. There may be something unused in the bytecode produced from the lambdas, but then it's a glitch of Java 8 and the tools should recognized it. Or maybe is sonarQube plain wrong. Anyway, look at their issue list.

Comment: @Lrrr I have no idea on which piece of code should remove this variable, IntelliJ doesn't accuse any variable not used.

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais I make a mistake, sorry :)

Comment: can you please show exact message from Sonar, as well as bigger code snippet? I mean, SonarQube may refer to some variables that are not used in lambda expressions, for example aValidation objects with null getSpec() value

Comment: I've recently had some wonky red squiggles in IDEA 14.1.3 when using nested lambdas like this, but the code compiles and runs fine.  I think there are a few bugs in various lambda parsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that code snippet, don't remove them. They are being used in places like `String nomeOriginal = aValidation.getSpec().get("peca_nome").toString()` and `cabecalhoNormalizado.put(novaChave, chave)`. Trying to remove them would almost certainly break the program, so I'm not sure why IntelliJ thinks that they are "unused."